# Google Maps Android JSON Array Polygon

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, polygon

I'm trying to create an array of polygons using latitude and longitude values from a JSON file hosted on my web server. I currently have the implementation working for a JSON array of markers, which populates the map with 40+ markers.

However, I'm having difficulties creating a Polygon to outline some buildings on my mapview using their coordinates.

Some of the errors include: cannot resolve method '.position(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)'

I understand that I have to implement a method to set the color, width, etc. for the polygon, but that's beyond my knowledge, and I'd hope that someone could help me out.

I've included the code in error from my MainActivity, the only activity I'm using in my app. I'll also include the current view of the app from my phone, and what I'd like to do with the polygon array as images.

If needed, I will provide more details.

**JSON array of markers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x7AE.png** (current state of my app)

**JSON array of polygons: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/273e0a8dee67740f6431/** (future state)

**Code in error**

```
 // Start polygon from JSON
protected void retrieveAndAddPolygon() throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        // Connect to the web service
        URL url = new URL(POLYGON_URL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Read the JSON data into the StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            json.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
        throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    // Create markers for the city data.
    // Must run this on the UI thread since it's a UI operation.
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                createPolygonFromJson(json.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
            }
        }
    });
}

void createPolygonFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
    JSONArray jsonArrayPoly = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayPoly.length(); i++) {
        // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArrayPoly.getJSONObject(i);
        map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                        //.title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                        .position(new LatLngPoly(
                                jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlngPoly").getDouble(0),
                                jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlngPoly").getDouble(1)
                        ))
        );
    }
}
// End polygon from JSON
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.ramap;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polygon;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "RaMap";

    private static final String SERVICE_URL =                  "http://nrdyninja.com/android/ramap/locations.json";

private static final String POLYGON_URL =    "http://nrdyninja.com/android/ramap/locationsPoly.json";

protected GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  // references layout/main.xml to the initial view
    setUpMapIfNeeded();             // sets up the MapView

    // Used for finding current location with button
    // Will eventually pass current location into a value so that markers
    // are populated when they're 5m from current location.
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    final TextView locationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkInLocation);
    Button getAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkInButton);

    getAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String answer = "Checked Into <location name here>"; //
            locationText.setText(answer);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is
    // present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); //uses menu/main.xml <item> to populate
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_normal:
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_hybrid:
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_satellite:
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (map != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    // Retrieve the city data from the web service
    // In a worker thread since it's a network operation.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                retrieveAndAddCities();
                retrieveAndAddPolygon();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot retrieve cities", e);
                return;
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

protected void retrieveAndAddCities() throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        // Connect to the web service
        URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Read the JSON data into the StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            json.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
        throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    // Create markers for the city data.
    // Must run this on the UI thread since it's a UI operation.
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                createMarkersFromJson(json.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
            }
        }
    });
}


// Start polygon from JSON
protected void retrieveAndAddPolygon() throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        // Connect to the web service
        URL url = new URL(POLYGON_URL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Read the JSON data into the StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            json.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
        throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    // Create markers for the city data.
    // Must run this on the UI thread since it's a UI operation.
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                createPolygonFromJson(json.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
            }
        }
    });
}

void createPolygonFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
    JSONArray jsonArrayPoly = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayPoly.length(); i++) {
        // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArrayPoly.getJSONObject(i);
        map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                        //.title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                        .position(new LatLngPoly(
                                jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlngPoly").getDouble(0),
                                jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlngPoly").getDouble(1)
                        ))
        );
    }
}
// End polygon from JSON


void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                        .snippet(Integer.toString(jsonObj.getInt("check ins")))
                        .position(new LatLng(
                                jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                                jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1)
                        ))
        );
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As i understand, you correctly retrieveing all points and now want to show polygon of this points?

It is really simple.

```
GoogleMap map;
// ... get a map.
// Add a triangle in the Gulf of Guinea
Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
 .add(new LatLng(0, 0), new LatLng(0, 5), new LatLng(3, 5), new LatLng(0, 0))
 .strokeColor(Color.RED)
 .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

It is taken from official documentation.
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon.html

You code should look like this:

```
void createPolygonFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
// De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.RED);
polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.BLUE);
JSONArray jsonArrayPoly = new JSONArray(json);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayPoly.length(); i++) {
    // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArrayPoly.getJSONObject(i);
    polygonOptions.add(new LatLng(jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlngPoly").getDouble(0),jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlngPoly").getDouble(1)));
    );
}
Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
```

}

Comment: Should I also add:

    createPolygonFromJson(json.toString());

To the runOnUiThread?

Comment: @LordBahamut, Yes. You Should never touch your UI from background Thread.

Comment: Hm, seems that it didn't work. It's not creating the polygon shape on the map view. Perhaps my JSON values are incorrectly formatted?

Comment: @LordBahamut, try first example, just to be sure that polygon is really creating(my first snippet of code).
Then try to check you json values.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate the correct results, however, I will continue to test until it works. I will accept your answer in a few days once I manage to get it to work.